# How to fix `java: Cannot run program "..." (in directory "..."): error=0 Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: xxxx, signal: xx` issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ssh, remote-development

I ran my Java application using JetBrains Client remote development, as you see, I have encountered an issue with `java: Cannot run program "..." (in directory "..."): error=0 Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: xxx, signal: 11` prompt in dialog, and how to fix it.

[image]

Could you help me and fix the issue to run my Java application successfully?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem of a JDK distro on the local machine. Please check that the JDK, the build process runs on, has an executable named "jspawnhelper" in a jre/lib subdirectory. The "jspawnhelper" should have proper executing permissions. To run build process IDE usually uses the most recent JDK associated with the project. It is important to check the JDK that launches a program and not a program being launched (in our case this is a different VM executable)

Alternatively, you may try to configure JDK to use older launching mechanism by adding flag to **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | * build process VM options text field**

`-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork`

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on jenkins in ubuntu. It had java jdk 17 version on it, I simply upgraded (`sudo apt install openjdk-21-jdk`) java version to java jdk 21, and the problem is solved